# Get branch name in Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

In my Dockerfile I copy and build my frontend:

```
FROM node:8.11 as frontend
COPY frontend/package.json /frontend/package.json
COPY ./VERSION /frontend/VERSION
WORKDIR /frontend
RUN npm install
COPY frontend/ /frontend
RUN sed -i "s|VERSION|frontend@$(cat "VERSION")|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
RUN npm run build-prod
```

I want to change the following line:

```
RUN sed -i "s|VERSION|frontend@$(cat "VERSION")|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
```

to have a branch name at the beginning so it would look like:

```
RUN sed -i "s|VERSION|`**BRANCH_NAME**`-frontend@$(cat "VERSION")|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
```

so I want to get Branch name in my dockerfile somehow. 
but I'm not sure is it possible to use branch/commit names in dockerfile?

this is my gitlab-ci.yaml file:

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" registry.xx.xx
  script:
    - export TARGET=frontend
    - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$TARGET
    - docker pull $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME || echo "no branch image"
    - docker pull $IMAGE:latest || echo "no latest image"
    - docker build --target $TARGET -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

    - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
    - docker pull $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME || echo "no branch image"
    - docker pull $IMAGE:latest || echo "no latest image"
    - docker build -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  tags:
    - local-docker
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is add an `ARG` in your `Dockerfile` called `BRANCH_NAME` and pass it in with `--build-arg`.

Below will create a build arg that defaults to master if no build arg is passed to the docker build:

```
FROM node:8.11 as frontend

ARG BRANCH_NAME=master
...
...
```

Your pipeline will include a docker build step like the following:

```
docker build -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --build=arg BRANCH_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
```

From there, you can use the argument as a variable in your Dockerfile.

Comment: sorry for noob question, but with this will the gitlab-cli.yaml file have BRANCH_NAME=master (because ARG BRANCH_NAME=master was declared) 
or Dockerfile will have $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME (that's what I'm trying to get)?

Comment: thank you so much! I got it! `    - docker build --target $TARGET -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --build-arg BRANCH_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
` and  `ARG BRANCH_NAME
`

Comment: You're welcome and glad you figured it out. I set the ARG BRANCH_NAME=master because I like to default variables even if you will override it 100% of the time. Just a habit but of course not necessary. Good luck with the rest of your pipeline improvements!

Comment: I just noticed when I have `- docker build --target $TARGET -t $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME --build-arg BRANCH_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .` frontend is built twice, do you know why this could be?

Comment: `--build=arg` should be `--build-arg`

Answer (score 1):

There are several environment variables that could help you achieve this like `CI_EXTERNAL_PULL_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`, `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`, `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`

Initially, I will say `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is the one working for you.
However, which one you should use will depend on what conditions are triggering the jobs or even the setup of your YAML file. Look at the following link to check which is your best fit for your jobs and the considerations that it will need.: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM node:8.11 as frontend
COPY frontend/package.json /frontend/package.json
COPY ./VERSION /frontend/VERSION
WORKDIR /frontend
RUN npm install
COPY frontend/ /frontend
RUN sed -i "s|VERSION|frontend@$(cat "VERSION")|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
RUN npm run build-prod
```

I dont know about gitlab's CI. But i see that you've just copied frontend to /frontend. I assume you have .git folder inside frontend, no?

If that is the case, why dont you use it? Just after you copy frontend :

```
RUN cd /frontend/ &&  BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2) && export BRANCH_NAME
```

So now you have BRANCH_NAME as environment variable.

```
RUN sed -i "s|VERSION|`$BRANCH_NAME`-frontend@$(cat "VERSION")|g" src/environments/environment.prod.ts
```